# How to auto-format dates in custom tooltip formatter?

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts does a great job auto-formatting dates both on the x-axis and in tooltips. Unfortunately I need a custom function to format my y-values, and `/plotOptions/line/tooltip/pointFormat` accepts only a format string and not a function, so I have to set `/tooltip/formatter` instead. How do I get hold of the formatted date (e.g. Oct'13 or 20. Oct) as shown on the x axis? I don't seem to have access to `point.key` from there, only the raw millis value.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Fke4/

Comment: please put code on jsfiddle/plunker/jsbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is to pre-format the y-values and store them as part of the series data; the pre-formatted values can then be referenced from the tooltip `headerFormat` and `pointFormat`, where they can be used along with `{point.key}`, which contains the auto-formatted date (and which is not available when providing a custom tooltip `formatter`):

http://jsfiddle.net/uG3sv/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dateFormat()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29)

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
           return '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b\' %d',this.x) + ':</b> ' + this.y;
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Fke4/1/

Comment: The question is how to get the same, auto-adjusting format that it used for the x-axis labels (or in the tooltips, when not overriding the formatter).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this was answered in a Highcharts issue on [Github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2392)

```
formatter: function() {
                var tooltip = this.series.chart.tooltip,
                    item = this.point.getLabelConfig(),
                    header = this.series.chart.tooltip.tooltipFooterHeaderFormatter(item);

                return header + this.y;
            }
```

Corresponding fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Fke4/12/

If you are using a shared series:

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function (tooltip) {
          var header,
              s = [];

          $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            if(header == null) {
              var config = point.point.getLabelConfig();
              header = tooltip.tooltipFooterHeaderFormatter(config);
            }
            s.push(point.y);
          });

          return header + s.reverse().join('<br>');
        },
        shared: true
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

conver the raw milliseconds to a date object using

```
var currentDate = new Date (tome in milliseconds)
```

in the tootip/formatter function you have defined.

this will give you good control over the date. you can use currentDate.getMonth(), getDate(), getDay(), etc methods to get the information you want from that date.

build a string with the above info and return.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I'd like to make use of Highcharts' logic for figuring out how to best format a date (show just the year, year plus month etc, depending on the scale).